# javascript animation: Why does the next line run before the animation is done?

Tags: javascript, animation

I am having issues where I am trying to animate an element.  I have a recursive function animate that contains setTimeout to delay the animation.  The issue is that the next line after the recursive method is called gets run before the animation is called.  For example with this code:

```
this.slideTo = function(x,y) {
    var originalStyle = this.element.style.cssText;

    var endX = x;
    var endY = y;
    var pos = this.getPosition();
    var startX = pos.x;
    var startY = pos.y; 
    var distX = x - pos.x;
    var distY = y - pos.y;
    var totalDistance = Math.sqrt((distX*distX) + (distY*distY));
    var count = 0;
    var done = false;

    animate(this.element);
    function animate(element) {         
        count += 5;
        var curPos = _(element).getPosition();
        var curDistX =  endX - curPos.x;
        var curDistY = endY - curPos.y;
        var curDistance = Math.sqrt((curDistX*curDistX) + (curDistY*curDistY));
        var percentDone = count/totalDistance;
        var moveToX = Math.round((percentDone*distX) + startX);
        var moveToY = Math.round((percentDone*distY) + startY);
        _(element).moveTo(moveToX,moveToY);
        if(percentDone <= 1) {
            setTimeout(function(){animate(element);},1);
        } else {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    console.log(done);

    this.element.style.cssText = originalStyle;
}
```

The console displays false because it is run before the animation is done.  How can I solve this?  btw:  this is being called on a mouse event.  Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Because *setTimeout* runs asynchronously, the following lines of code run immediately, there's no pause for the *setTimeout*. It runs after the function completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next little changed code:

```
this.slideTo = function(x,y) {
    var originalStyle = this.element.style.cssText;

    var endX = x;
    var endY = y;
    var pos = this.getPosition();
    var startX = pos.x;
    var startY = pos.y; 
    var distX = x - pos.x;
    var distY = y - pos.y;
    var totalDistance = Math.sqrt((distX*distX) + (distY*distY));
    var count = 0;
    var done = false;

    function restoreState(element) {
        element.style.cssText = originalStyle;
        /// ....
    }

    function animate(element) {         
        count += 5;
        var curPos = _(element).getPosition();
        var curDistX =  endX - curPos.x;
        var curDistY = endY - curPos.y;
        var curDistance = Math.sqrt((curDistX*curDistX) + (curDistY*curDistY));
        var percentDone = count/totalDistance;
        var moveToX = Math.round((percentDone*distX) + startX);
        var moveToY = Math.round((percentDone*distY) + startY);
        _(element).moveTo(moveToX,moveToY);
        if(percentDone <= 1) {
            setTimeout(function(){animate(element);},1);
        } else {
            done = true;
            restoreState(element);
        }
    }

    animate(this.element);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because JS, and particularly `setTimeout`, is asynchronous -- that is, it doesn't block (sleep/wait/etc).  You're basically setting the timeout and then continuing on with the rest of the code.  JS calls your function when the time has elapsed and it's not doing anything else.

Most of the time, you can work around this by passing in a callback that you call when the animation completes (instead of or at the same time as setting `done`, would be the straightforward way).

Answer (score 0):

In short, setTimeout does not stop execution of your code -- it just runs the function in question after the given timeout:

```
var a = 'now';
function go(){ a = 'later'; };
setTimeout(go, 50);
console.log(a); // 'now'
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(a); },51); // 'later'
```

You want to use a callback pattern:

```
function animate(element, callback){
  // do some stuff
  if(stuffDone){
    callback();
  }
}
animate(element, function(){console.log(whatever); });
```